# How to delete more than one Global Secondary Index from the CloudFormation at once?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I have many Global Secondary Indexes described in the CloudFormation template. 
When I trying to delete more than one I get this error "An error occurred: TodosDynamoDbTable - Cannot perform more than one GSI creation or deletion in a single update.".

How can I delete more than one GSI from the template at once? Maybe I can remove them manually from the table and then perform template update or I can use some attribute(like "DependsOn")?

Comment: feature request: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/229

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible, at least not right now. You have to update your stack multiple times, removing one at a time.

Comment: How should the stack be updated multiple times? Let's say there is a huge release after months of work going to production. We are using a Serverless framework. So we may have all the code in place that uses those multiple GSIs. How would I edit this code to create 1 GSI at a time? If I removed a GSI , but it was being used in queries, wouldn't the deployment break? or is it that we can keep the GSI name in queries but create it after?

Answer (score 1):

As Miles mentioned, it's currently not possible using the standard CloudFormation template with a DynamoDB resource.
You can however create a custom resource in CloudFormation that triggers a Lambda that can create/update/delete GSIs as you